# AngularJS - unable to recieve data from server during ng-repeat iteration

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm building an app which receives a simple array with youtube video links, along with some other data. I'm constructing several `html` DOM elements using `ng-repeat`. Upon every iteration of the repeater I need to call a function and pass the current youtube link. That function call passes the link to the backend for further process and eventually returns an object in the following format:

```
var obj = {
    duration: "1H34M45S",
  more_data:{
    title: "some title",
    height: "200px",
    width: "100px",
    date_posted: "oct 2, 1734"
  }
}
```

Obviously my current implementation does not work (infinite loop). Whats the correct way of receiving and using the data during `ng-repeat` iteration?

HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="vid in videosArray">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(vid.url)}}" width="300" height="200" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <p>{{getVideoInfo(vid.url)}}</p> <!--here I need to acces the returned object and use the data. for example place the title / duration here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.getVideoInfo = function(videoUrl) {
  $http({
    url: "youtubeInfo.php",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: $.param({getInfo: videoUrl})
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
    return data; //data is an object
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
}
```

`edit`:
These are the errors i get in the console:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 1 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\controllers\youtubeInfo.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
{"duration":{"kind":"youtube#videoListResponse","etag":"\"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM\/Rk41fm-2TD0VG1yv0-bkUvcBi9s\"","pageInfo":{"totalResults":0,"resultsPerPage":0},"items":[]},"vid_data":null}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

`edit2` - even if I change the JS function to return the data via `$scope`, I still get the error above in an infinite loop.

```
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.test = data;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) { });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(vid.url)}}" width="300" height="200" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <p>{{getVideoInfo(vid.url)}}</p><span>{{test.duration}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the output for console.log

Answer (score 0):

promise don't return data value, instead you should do assingment in success

```
function(videoUrl) {
  $http({
    url: "youtubeInfo.php",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: $.param({getInfo: videoUrl})
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.getVideoInfo = data; //data is an object
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
}
```

[See this](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/)

Comment: What do you mean by `promise don't return data value`?

Comment: See the link in uptaded answer

Comment: I asked you specifically because, its totally incorrect statement `promise don't return data value`.

Comment: Isn't it a promise `$http`?

Comment: Your solution seems OK, but the explanation has incorrect `information` about promise, "promise don't return data value". Basically isn't a problem..promise has capability to return data to follow chain promise mechanism.. FYI the problem is `getVideoInfo(vid.url)` used on view would get a value even if we return it from the `getVideoInfo` function..that's why you need to assign it to scope variable after $http call succeeded

Comment: Promise has capability to return data to follow chain promise mechanism, could you give a link, to see what it means clearly?

Comment: I think this would be [great article](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/06/04/angularjs-promises-2/)

Comment: @PankajParkar I updated my post with your advises, I still get the same errors in an infinite loop.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling $http call in such a way by placing it inside `{{}}`, because it will call that ajax on each digedigest loop + its own digest..after $http completion

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
      {{getVideoInfo(vid.url).duration}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use $resource here because it returns an object that gets populated once the request is finished and thus can be easily used in your template.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

So you should end up with sth like this (not tested):

```
var VideoInfo = $resource('youtubeInfo.php', null, { 'get': {method:'POST'} }); // BTW: Think about if this request needs POST as method...

$scope.getVideoInfo = function(videoUrl) {
  return VideoInfo.get({getInfo: videoUrl}, function(value, responseHeaders) {
   // Do some logging or whatever...
  });
}
```

In your template you should use ng-init to do the request once and then use the object as you like

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="vid in videosArray" ng-init="videoInfo = getVideoInfo(vid.url)">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
  <iframe ng-src="{{trustSrc(vid.url)}}" width="300" height="200" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <p>{{videoInfo.title}} {{videoInfo.duration}}</p>
 </div>
```